# To reduce the calendar size

Tags: html, asp.net, datepicker

In the below code i have a date picker when i click to open the date picker the Date label goes down and i want to reduce the size of calendar pls help me to do this.

code:

```
<table id="TblDate" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td width="50Px">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td width="150Px">
          <input type='text' id='sel' onclick='dispCal()' size=10 readonly='readonly' />
          <img src='img/calendar.png' onclick='dispCal()' style='cursor: pointer; vertical-align: middle;' />
          <table class='calendar' id='calendar' width="50Px">
            <tr class='monthdisp'>
                <td class='navigate' align='left'><img src='img/previous.png' onclick='return prev()' /></td>
                <td align='center' id='month'></td>
                <td class='navigate' align='right'><img src='img/next.png' onclick='return next()' /></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3>
                    <table id='dispDays' border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=4>                        
                    </table>                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        </td>
        <td width="40Px">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        </td>


    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to create your own datepicker? The jQuery datepicker is a much better solution to your problem. Have a look here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Date picker is working i want to reduce the size of calendar and label is moving down when i select

Comment: Your going to have to show us what dispCal() is doing then. Do you have a css file referenced on this page or any styles? Its all in one table row, which you have not set the width for...